# Having trouble with pointer to 2D array declaration

Tags: arrays, pointers

i have some problem with pointer to 2D array declaration,

I write some code below:

```
typedef int ptr2di[3][3];
void main()
{
int a[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

ptr2di *ptr=&a;
//ptr2di *ptr=a;

cout << a << endl << &a;
}
```

Output:

```
0029F940

0029F940
```

Conclude: a = &a = base address of array. 
Then I change a little bit at `ptr2di` declaration:

```
//ptr2di *ptr=&a;
ptr2di *ptr=a;
```

It has a error C2440: 'initializing' : connot convert from 'int [3][3]' to 'ptr2di (*)'.

So, this is my problem, i can't understand what is the difference between `a` and `&a`?
Could everybody help me explain that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the value of a is actually 0029F940 (because it is an array) and cout is just looking at the value, but the compiler sees a as the array int[3][3] and will not allow the assignment of that to ptr2di *, which is expecting a pointer to an int[3][3].  So, the value of a and &a is the same, but the type is different and the compiler is checking the types for legal assignment.

Similar example:

```
int a = 1;
// Valid: Assigning the address of a (which is an int) to a pointer to an int
int *ptr = &a;

// Invalid: Assigning an the int a to a pointer to an int
int *ptr = a;
```

What happens if you do this?
    cout << a[0][0] << endl << &a;